# hosting wordpress on appfog

Tags: wordpress, appfog

I'm planning to host a *Wordpress* Blog on **AppFog**.
As i'm novice and their documentation seems to be lacking details, i want to know that if my Data will be preserved if any instance goes down ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have a persistent filesystem yet, so it not only MAY, but rather WILL go down at some point.
You'd better use a remote repository and host it on your local machine, and update your wordpress from there. 
Right now, AppFog is quite different from cpanel's hosting you're most probably used to.
The wp.stackoverflow.com should have docs on git and AppFog, start there.

Comment: Thanks for info. n well it is wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I really like the concept of this remote repository. Can u direct me to some source, which details the method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

AppFog uses ephemeral file storage which means any media files, plugins and themes you upload via the adim panel will not persist after a restart.  You will need to add plugins and themes to your local source file and use git to push them to the server. For media files (images, etc.) you will need to use a third-party like Amazon S3 to store the static files.

If you go the S3 route there is a Wordpress plugin that will help you with setting up Wordpress to push files to your S3 buckets: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tantan-s3-cloudfront/